# DAX Proportion of balance by state and date

Tags: ssas, dax, powerpivot

I am currently attempting to use DAX queries to calculate the proportion of the balance attributed to each State in my analysis cube, from the following image:

[image: Initial data]

I currently have a Sales table with a ReportDateKey that joins a ReportDate table that has a DateKey

If I use the following statement:

```
AllCurrentBalanceByDate:=CALCULATE([TotalCurrentBalance],ALLSELECTED())
```

It gives me the overall total, ignoring the date altogether, which is a useless figure.

If I enter the following query and display it in the excel spreadsheet:

```
AllCurrentBalanceByDate:=CALCULATE([TotalCurrentBalance],ALLSELECTED('Report Date'[Month]))
```

it is returning the same data as found in the Balance column. Again, useless. I need a total for each month, so that I can calculate the state balance / overall total for that month to get the proportion/percentage attributable to that State.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you want your measure to ignore whichever State is selected, you need to include the State columns in your ALL filter.

Also I suppose you want to use `ALL` instead of `ALLSELECTED` as your overall balance per month shouldn't be affected by external filters on state (but this depends on your use case)?

```
AllCurrentBalanceByDate:=CALCULATE(SUM([CurrentBalance]),ALL(Geography[StateName]))
```

Comment: As an addition to this, I found that if I want the Overall Current Balance independently of whatever level I am in the Geography hierarchy, I needed OverallCurrentBalance:=CALCULATE(SUM([CurrentBalance]),ALL(Geography)). That will remove all filters applied from the Geography table.